# How to make inactive maven dependecies - active?

Tags: java, maven

Maven dependecies library has inactive content.
See screenshot pls
I cant import grey icons.
what shouls i do to make them active? rebuild project doest help.

[image]

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: im guessing eclipse shows provided dependencies with darker color